# Do I need Github self-hosted runners in order to deploy behind a firewall

Tags: github, github-actions, firewall

We are looking to replace our existing infrastructure of SVN and Bamboo with Github and Github actions.  We use Bamboo to deploy to our intranet behind a firewall using Ant scripts.  Is the only way that Github actions can deploy to our intranet is if we use a self hosted runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're on GitHub Enterprise Cloud and have access to the Large Runner feature, self-hosted runners are the only way to put a safe hole in your firewalled environment. The default GitHub hosted runners are running inside of Azure and can have virtually any IP address.

Even when using self-hosted runners behind your corporate firewall, you may want to isolate the runner.

[Large Runners have an option to put them behind a proxy that will provide them with a fixed IP address](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/using-larger-runners#networking-for-larger-runners), in which case you can allow-list that specific IP address in your firewall.

> By default, larger runners receive a dynamic IP address that changes for each job run. Optionally, GitHub Enterprise Cloud customers can configure their larger runners to receive a static IP address from GitHub's IP address pool. When enabled, instances of the larger runner will receive an address from a range that is unique to the runner, allowing you to use this range to configure a firewall allowlist. You can use up to 10 static IP address ranges in total across all your larger runners.